# App Crashes on Launch w/ Testflight

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm having problems with an app that we previously submitted to Apple for submission that they asked us to re-do a simple marketing issue (we needed to remove an image of an app screen which had third party apps).

Unfortunately, now when I have prepared the app for re-submission and I distribute it via Testflight the app crashes on launch. A subsequent launch works, however. This only happens with the Testflight build - when I do a Release build from Xcode using a production provisioning profile it works, and when I do a debug build it works. Thinking I must have made a mistake I pulled the exact commit from my repo for the previous submission, but it is now crashing the exact same way.

Only my ipad mini 2 reports the crash logs via the Xcode Organizer (my iPhone 6 does not), and they read like this (though I checked the box to include the debug symbols):

```
Incident Identifier: BDC2E493-9794-42D8-B9F6-F74DEF432AA2
Beta Identifier:     F34F1B0B-44F0-4E9C-A8F6-46861EDB0B39
Hardware Model:      iPad4,4
Process:             My App [6660]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1EDC2E96-E4E0-4148-AF7D-478A8C2FA5D9/My App.app/My App
Identifier:          com.myco.My-App
Version:             29 (1.0)
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-10-02 11:49:41.41 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-10-02 11:49:39.39 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.0 (13A341)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001004b4f5c
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001004b4f5c specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt) -> () + 44
1   My App                      0x000000010011bb50 0x1000fc000 + 129872
2   My App                      0x000000010010e954 0x1000fc000 + 76116
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198b817b0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:761)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198b81770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:513)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198b86e20 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844 (inline_internal.h:1063)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a78258 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1615)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a760c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628 (CFRunLoop.c:2721)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839a4dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
9   GraphicsServices                0x000000018e920088 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2247)
10  UIKit                           0x000000018907ef60 UIApplicationMain + 204 (UIApplication.m:3663)
11  My App                      0x000000010011afe8 0x1000fc000 + 126952
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000198bb28b8 start + 4 (start_glue.s:80)
```

I can't figure out what's causing this, nor how I'll be able to test and confirm it's fix without re-submitting to Testflight and waiting.

I suspect this may be an Apple problem, but I'm nervous about re-submitting knowing there may be a crash in my app. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Comment: @ErikPerik was never able to resolve it, but finally gave up and submitted the app... and it was accepted! So I guess Apple/Testflight bug but can be ignored.

Comment: You're using Swift and do you have push notifications enabled? Can share the didLaunchWithOptions method to see whats happening there?