# "Fatal error" crash at "if let"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, fatal-error

I get a crash that has no information other than it's a fatal error. I can see it in 'Organiser' in Xcode and it points to the following line:

[image]

I can't reproduce it on a device where I work or on a simulator. It happens when someone uses a beta from TestFlight.

```
#0  (null) in specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never ()
#1  (null) in specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never ()
#2  (null) in ...TableViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt : IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell at ...TableViewController.swift:103
```

More code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "LCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! LTableViewCell        
    let l = ls[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = NSLocalizedString("dd/MM/yyyy", comment: "")

    if let date = l.date{            
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        cell.dateLabel.text = dateString
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: @Asdrubal I edited my question

Comment: try if l.date != nil instead

Comment: How is `ls` declared?

Comment: @TimVermeulen In the class brace: `var ls: [LObject] = []`
Then in viewDidLoad I fetch the list from Core Data.

Comment: @Questioner https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: @suhit why?! using "if let" is perfectly valid here if `l.date` is an Optional.

Comment: @Asdrubal What exactly am I missing in that article?

Comment: Perhaps it will provide you more understand of exceptions on the main thread. And you will be better able to figure out the problem. You could for example better understand a crash report, which could lead you to your solution.

Comment: For example, say you needed to make an update to your Core Data model to add the attribute "date".  You could run into migration problems which would cause your app to crash. Your device might run fine (if you deleted the app and ran it again), but the test flight app update won't because the model is now different.

Comment: @Asdrubal How would I find that out from this crash report? I've read the article. I've put the crash log into Xcode and it says `EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)`  It appears I'm not the only one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917322/app-crashes-on-launch-w-testflight <-- this guy has a very similar crash log to mine.

Comment: The section about Trace Trap [EXC_BREAKPOINT // SIGTRAP] might be helpful for you to understand your problem

Comment: @Asdrubal It wasn't. I've already looked through my code for places where a nil could have been unwrapped or something was cast wrong.

Comment: What happens when you try let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: l.date)

Comment: @Asdrubal I'll try that but since I can't reproduce this problem, I will have to wait until the person uses it and I get the crash report (both Crashlytics and Xcode take a while to get the logs) or don't get it. I don't see why it would work since by that line date is already assigned the value of l.date but I assume you know something I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved the problem. It was happening when the user's phone had its date and time set to display in a 12 hour format. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266271/4838107) and added the following line:

```
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB")
```

The crashes don't happen any more. I wish the crash logs weren't so useless. It would have saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-STACKTRACE) or [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) in order to better understand the source of the crash report. It appears as though you are trying to cast inside of an array on your line that creates the object that crashes. But often the source of the crash comes before then...

Try looking at your code on line 3:

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! LTableViewCell`

And see if the compiler makes you do this cast to `LTableViewCell` because of a warning or if that's something that you did. Often times it might build but it could lead to a crash because it's not a matching data type.

Comment: "It appears as though you are trying to cast inside of an array on your line that crashes"
What do you mean by this? Cast what and cast it inside of what array?

Comment: "And see if the compiler makes you do this cast to LTableViewCell because of a warning or if that's something that you did."
Makes me do it how?

Comment: this `ls[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]` - ls is an array of index `(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row` it's a little unconventional to do an array index that way, but if it works. Also the cast meaing the `as!` to `LTAbleViewCell` on the line that you declare the `l` object. The if statement where it's crashing is logically correct. So the crash is coming from when you create the variable you are comparing.

Comment: That or when you use `l.date` there is no `.date` for it to use. Is that a date object you created using something like `Date date = new Date()` kind of thing or is that part of the `DateFormatter` library?

Comment: I still don't get what you mean. What's wrong with the casts? And why is it logically correct for the crash to be at the if statement?

Comment: its logically correct because you are allowed to make an if comparison and declare a variable at the same line, to save space... So the only other reason the compiler would point to that line is if the actual comparison you are making `date = l.date` is illegal and causes a crash. remove the let from the if line declare it above then make the comparison in the if statement using `if (date == l.date)` that might fix it